# Debugging a NumPy TypeError? [edited from previous ValueError]

Tags: python, numpy

I was writing the code below and was getting the error:

**TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars**

The issue is at the **"if statement and agrmnt variable"**, but don't know why because  **"agrmnt"** variable is type int. I am not sure why I can't use a conditional statement here.

```
import numpy as np

feature_matrix= np.array([[ 0.1837462,  0.29989789, -0.35889786, -0.30780561, -0.44230703, -0.03043835,
   0.21370063,  0.33344998, -0.40850817, -0.13105809],
 [ 0.08254096,  0.06012654,  0.19821234,  0.40958367,  0.07155838, -0.49830717,
   0.09098162,  0.19062183, -0.27312663,  0.39060785],
 [-0.20112519, -0.00593087,  0.05738862,  0.16811148, -0.10466314, -0.21348009,
   0.45806193, -0.27659307,  0.2901038,  -0.29736505],
 [-0.14703536, -0.45573697, -0.47563745, -0.08546162, -0.08562345,  0.07636098,
  -0.42087389, -0.16322197, -0.02759763,  0.0297091 ],
 [-0.18082261,  0.28644149, -0.47549449, -0.3049562,   0.13967768,  0.34904474,
   0.20627692,  0.28407868,  0.21849356, -0.01642202]])
labels = np.array([-1, -1, -1,  1, -1])
T= 10
L= 0.1456692551041303

    tta = np.zeros((feature_matrix[0].size)).reshape(-1,1)
    tta_0 = 0
    for t in range(T):
        for i in range(feature_matrix.shape[0]):
            agrmnt = np.asscalar(labels[i]*(int(np.dot(feature_matrix[i][np.newaxis], tta)) + tta_0))
            if agrmnt<=1:
                tta = (1-(L*1/((t+1)**0.5))*tta)+(1/((t+1)**0.5)* 
                         (labels[i]*feature_matrix[i][np.newaxis])))
                tta_0 = tta_0 + (labels[i]*1/((t+1)**0.5))
            else:
                tta = (1-(L*((t+1)**0.5))*tta[np.newaxis].T)
                tta_0 = tta_0

    print(tta,tta_0)
```

Can someone check why and point me in the right direction?

Comment: `A@B`  is matrix multiplication.  Last dim of A pairs with the 2nd to the last dim of B

Comment: I edited the issue above and now i am getting the TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars. I am not sure why I can't use an Int type in a conditional statement since "agrmnt" variable of type int. Thanks.

Comment: Is the error in the `asscalar` call?  `np.asscalar(np.array([1,2]))` produces this error.

Comment: I don't think so. I tried val.item() to change agrmnt to type int and got exactly same error. The weird thing is this code works fine for other algorithms. Only change i made was setting the "if statment" from <= 0 to <=1 and made changes to the update conditions in the if and else if statements. Not sure if this is a bug in Python. I will try to convert the ndarray to list of lists and see if that works.

Comment: Did you check the size of: `labels[i]*(int(np.dot(feature_matrix[i][np.newaxis], tta)) + tta_0)`.  This could produce a single value for some iterations, and then more than one with others.  You are changing `tta` and `tta_0` with each iteration.

Comment: The traceback should be tell you exactly which line is causing the problem.  If it's a long line, you can always split the calculation into several pieces to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I already checked. Size of labels[i]*(int(np.dot(feature_matrix[i][np.newaxis], tta)) + tta_0) is 1 if you isolate that. This code works if you don't have the inner "for loop," i.e., for a single first iteration. However, when it's in there, and you try to initiate t >1, it pops up with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy-n-paste your code, and correcting one syntax error:

```
1256:~/mypy$ python3 stack56844635.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack56844635.py", line 21, in <module>
    agrmnt = np.asscalar(labels[i]*(int(np.dot(feature_matrix[i][np.newaxis], tta)) + tta_0))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Clearly the error is in the `asscalar` line.

changing the code to read:

```
    temp = labels[i]*(int(np.dot(feature_matrix[i][np.newaxis], tta)) + tta_0)
    print(temp)
    agrmnt = np.asscalar(temp)
```

I get

```
1259:~/mypy$ python3 stack56844635.py 
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack56844635.py", line 21, in <module>
    temp = labels[i]*(int(np.dot(feature_matrix[i][np.newaxis], tta)) + tta_0)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

So it apparently performed on iteration just fine, producing a 0 value; but the next loop causes an error.  But looking more carefully at that line, I see a `int()`.  That would produce the same error.

Take that out:

```
    temp = labels[i]*(np.dot(feature_matrix[i][np.newaxis], tta) + tta_0)
    print(temp)
    agrmnt = np.asscalar(temp)

1300:~/mypy$ python3 stack56844635.py 
[[-0.]]
[[ 0.41001225  0.49396662  0.01778946  0.0547189  -0.04249864  0.25519979
   0.4316633   0.51821805 -0.01806885  0.1824719 ]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack56844635.py", line 23, in <module>
    agrmnt = np.asscalar(temp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 547, in asscalar
    return a.item()
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Now the error moves to the `ascalar` (which uses `.item()`).

In the first iteration `temp` is a (1,1) array (not surprising from an `np.dot`).  The next iteration is a (1,10) array.  That can't be converted into a scalar, either with `int` or `asscalar`.

I've pointed out the error location and issue.  And suggested ways of debugging.  But I won't try to solve this for you - you need to track the array dimensions carefully.  Don't try to cheat in wrap things in `int` and `asscalar` commands.

Initially `tta` is (10,1) array, but after the 1st loop it is (10,10).

Comment: Of course, I pointed out in the original post that issue is at the agrmnt variable where the asscalar line is at. The whole purpose of that line is to arrive at an integer that can be used in the "if statement." The dot product on that line arrived at an array of size 1, which was converted to an int type. The output of that line is a numpy.int32 of size 1. np.asscalar() and val.item() checks it is converted to int type, then Python gives you that error that implies that line is not size 1. Not sure what is going on here, that is why I am confused.

Comment: thanks @ hpaulj, let me try a few things and see if that works.

Comment: I figured it out, so I decided to post it here so someone can probably learn from it. The issue was not necessarily the np.asscalar() line. Though you and I agreed there it was an issue there and the code kept increasing the size of the tta array. 

The Issue was the tta line immediately after the if statement. I was adding an nx1 and 1xn array, instead of the same dimension i.e., nx1 and nx1 or 1xn and 1xn arrays. I did a transpose of one the arrays, and it fixed it. Most debuggers like flagging issues after the fact, so one have to look shortly before.  Thanks again @hpaulj